# I want to append the date and drop duplicates and save the file in parquet format in one command

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

```
dbutils.widgets.text("startdate","")
dbutils.widgets.text("output_path","")

start_date_str = dbutils.widgets.get("startdate")
if not re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', start_date_str):
  raise ValueError("Invalid input, startdate widget should be in the format yyyy-mm-dd")

ls = start_date_str.split('-')
start_date = date(int(ls[0]), int(ls[1]), int(ls[2]))
end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=12*10) - timedelta(days=1)
print(start_date, end_date)

date_range = spark.range(0, (end_date - start_date).days, 1) \
.withColumn("date", date_add(lit(start_date), col("id").cast("int")))

dim_time = date_range \
.withColumn("TimeId", monotonically_increasing_id()+1) \
.withColumn("DayOfWeek", date_format(col("date"), "EEEE")) \
.withColumn("CurrentDay", when(col("date") == current_date(), 1).otherwise(0)) \
.withColumn("WorkingDay", when(col("DayOfWeek").isin(["Saturday", "Sunday"]), 0).otherwise(1)) \
.withColumn("MonthId", month(col("date")).cast("smallint")) \
.withColumn("MonthDesc", date_format(col("date"), "MMMM")) \
.withColumn("QuarterId", quarter(col("date")).cast("smallint")) \
.withColumn("QuarterDesc", concat(lit("Q"), quarter(col("date")).cast("string"))) \
.withColumn("Year", year(col("date")).cast("smallint")) \
.select("Timeid", "date", "DayOfWeek", "CurrentDay", "WorkingDay", "MonthId", "MonthDesc", "QuarterId", "QuarterDesc", "Year")

display(dim_time)
dim_time.write.format('parquet').mode('append').save(output_path)

dim_time2 = spark.read.format("parquet") \
     .load(output_path) \
     .dropDuplicates(['date'])

dim_time2.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save(output_path)
```

I don't want to write it and read it then drop duplicates and again write it. i want everything to happen in one go. please get me the most efficient way to replace the last past of the code.I want data to get populated for 10 years in the first time. again when the date is chaneged the extra data should be appended and duplicates should be droped.

Comment: The schema of the data you want to add would be same if my understanding is correct. Clarify if I'm wrong

Comment: yes the schema is the same. first time when my startdate is 2020-01-01 i will get the data from 2020-01-01 to 2029-12-31. next second time if i change the startdate to 2018-01-01 i want the data from 2018-01-01 to 2029-12-31 without duplicates,please help me with this

Comment: Can you include the libraries imported as well in the code used above?

Comment: # import functions
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import *
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
import re

Answer (score 0):

- You can check whether the output path exists or not before writing it. If the path does not exist, then that indicates that you are writing the file for first time. So just write the file.
- If the path already exists (indicating the presence of previous data), then you can read that file into a dataframe, union it with the current dataframe, and then drop duplicates.
- Use can use the following code after creating `dim_time`  dataframe.

[image]

```
import os
op_path = dbutils.widgets.get("output_path")
#print(op_path)

#I am using dbfs so I am concatenating '/dbfs' to op_path (value of op_path is '/FileStore/first')
if(len(os.listdir('/dbfs'+op_path))==0):
    print("no path")
    dim_time.write.format('parquet').save(op_path)
else:
    print("path is present")
    data = spark.read.format('parquet').load(op_path)
    #display(data)
    final_data = dim_time.union(data).dropDuplicates(['date'])
    display(final_data)
    final_data.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save(op_path)
```

[image]

Comment: here the file is first wrote then read and again wrote , too many input output functions .is there any alternative to do this

Comment: the file will be written only the first time. From the next time, file is read, appended with dim_time dataframe, drop duplicates and write to directly.